# SVG Filter inset shadow not working in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, svg-filters

Hello I'm trying to apply this svg inset shadow filter to my div. Is working fine in Chrome but not in Safari.

Here's the svg filter:

```
<filter id="inset" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%">
  <feOffset dx="0.00" dy="0.00"></feOffset>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.1" result="offset-blur"></feGaussianBlur>
  <feComposite operator="out" in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" result="inverse"></feComposite>
  <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.8" result="color"></feFlood>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="color" in2="inverse" result="shadow"></feComposite>
  <feComposite operator="over" in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inset-shadow"></feComposite>
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.0012"></feGaussianBlur>
  <feOffset dx="0.013" dy="0.013" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
  <feFlood flood-color="black"></feFlood>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"></feComposite>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="inset-shadow"></feMergeNode>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Where's the problem?

**Note:** The child where I' trying to applying this filter has a clip-path polygon property

[Chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke9sg.png)

[Safari result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HpKp.png)

Comment: Maybe you have to check the differences between the engines that each browser uses

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not support certain SVG filter primitives when they're used via a CSS filter. feComposite/out is one of them.

Comment: The only proper workaround is to do things completely in inline SVG. I thought I had a clever workaround using feComponentTransfer but Safari doesn't support opacity manipulation when it's in a CSS filter either.